# class library and security in dotnet technology

Tags: c#

suppose i have developed class library and i want the i can use this library in my project only but if someone try to copy the dll file and want to use it in his project then he will not be able to do so. so i just want to know how could embed this type of security in the dll file...please tell me all ways. thanks

Comment: The only really secure way to prevent this is not to ship your DLL.

Comment: If you hold down the Shift key while typing an alpha character, it will produce that character in upper case.

Comment: Henk +1 Tergiver +1 for smart comments :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application verify license enforement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064038/application-verify-license-enforement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could verify in your assembly the PublicKeyToken of the calling signed assembly.

- [How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx)
- [Getting an Assembly's Public Key the Programmatic way](http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2004/03/04/84293.aspx)

The second example is in VB.NET, couldn't find a C# version readily but you'll get the idea.

**Be aware** that this is not an absolutly secure way, because someone could still decompile your assembly. But if it's just to prevent that your library is used in other projects, this might be an acceptable way.

Comment: first of all how to assign PublicKeyToken to dll and then how could i check writing code. please help me in detail with code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Check the signature of the calling assembly and sign the assembly you are calling the dll from. Then sign the dll.

Comment: Your answer is not very much clear.....will you please explain in detail with code snippet which enable me to implement it properly. thanks

Comment: @Tim: A decompiler won't help you against a private-public key. Additionally, there is an obfuscator that (statically) links the .NET framework, so you can't disassemble, neither with Dis# nor with IDA Pro Advanced.

Comment: I don't need to worry about the key; I can disassemble the binary and remove the check. Obfuscators just obfuscate, i.e. make it harder to decipher the code; they don't encrypt it. People were reverse-engineering protection well before Reflector etc. arrived.

Comment: @Tim: That's just my point. If .NET is statically linked, you can't decompile it, neither with a .NET decompiler (Dis#/Reflector) nor with a C++ decompiler, yet. And if it is signed, you can't just change something, that will change the signature, which means it will fail to run.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke a licensing technology when the library was to be instantiated. What I've done in the past is include a public key as a resource to the dll, and then look for a license xml document with a cryptographic signature signed with my private key. As long as I keep close track of my private key, it's pretty difficult to defeat.

Having said that, .Net is *eminently* decompilable - be sure and obfuscate it with a tool like Dotfuscator.

Comment: after reading your answer i got few question. 1) how to invoke licensing technology when i will develop class library. 2) how to add public key as a resource to the dll 3) how to look for a license xml document with a cryptographic signature signed with my private key and from where & when to look. it will be better if u please give me a sample application. thanks a lot

Comment: I can't give the precise code I use, because it's IP of my employer, but I can give you some more specific direction.                                             I would start by creating a static class, License, with a static method Invoke. I would place a call to this method within the constructor of your library (or factory method, if that's how you roll). Within the Invoke method, you're looking in the local directory (or a configured license directory if you prefer) for a file, "license.xml". If you don't find it, you throw an exception, maybe "UnlicenseUsageException".

Comment: If you do find it, you take the Xml therein, and remove the last node which contains the signature. You then verify the signature bytes against the Xml without the signature node (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx). If it fails, it throws the aforementioned exception. All done.

Comment: Last thing - you need to write a small app that generates the license file and signs it with your private key (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx).

Comment: FYI, looks like @Thomas turned this into [a follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762646/class-library-security-license-technology)...

Answer (score 2):

Not secure but much harder to abuse: You can integrate the dll into your main exe or web.dll using

- [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to Merge them together or
- [embed your application’s dependent DLLs as a resource inside your EXE file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)